# Confusion regarding references in implementation of a double linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, reference

I am trying out my own implementation of a double-linked list. While my code is currently functioning, I can't really figure out why. Below is an exerpt of the code:

```
public class DLList<E> {

    public class Node {
        /** The contents of the node is public */
        public E elt;

        protected Node prev, next;

        Node() {
            this(null);
        }

        Node(E elt) {
            this.elt = elt;
            prev = next = null;
        }
    }

    Node first, last;

    DLList() {
        first = last = null;
    }

       // inserts an element at the beginning of the list 
    public Node addFirst(E e) {
        Node node = new Node(e);
        if(first==null){
            first = node;
            last = node;
        }else{
            node.next = first;
            first.prev = node;
            first = node;
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

In the else-block of the addFirst-function the variable `next` is set to the reference `first` and two lines later the reference `first` is set to the Node-object `node`. Surspringly (to me) this works. Shouldn't this mean that `node.next` is actually set to `node` as we basically get `node.next = first = node`? 


EDIT:
Answers:

You're changing references (pointers) - which is why it does [work]. The last line `first = node;` simply changes `first` from pointing to the previous node to point to the current node. – alfasin


I think I figured it out. In my code I am not changing the actual object, I am just changing what objects are being referenced. In plain english my code in the else-block can be read as: 
1. Set `node.next` to reference the object that `first` is referencing. 
2. Set `first.prev` to reference the object that `node` is referencing. 
3. Lastly, reassign `first` to reference the object that `node` is referencing. – erikejan

Comment: Not only it isn't working - it won't even compile: the object `first` was never declared or assigned before use... Further, even if it *was* working - you wouldn't be able to insert more than two elements: each time you would add a new element it would override another one with the current implementation.

Comment: @alfasin Yeah, sorry about that. I copied a section of the code and forgot to include some things. It has been edited now.

Comment: You acknowledged only the first part of my comment. Your *real* issue is in the second part...

Comment: @alfasin I copied the code in my post and ran it. I was able to add more than two elements and then print these out by traversing the list both forwards and backwards. I am afraid I don't know what you mean.

Comment: My bad, with the added lines it should work just fine. You're changing references (pointers) - which is why it does. The last line `first = node;` simply changes `first` from pointing to the previous node to point to the *current* node.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code as mentioned in the comments, but to answer your question, no, it's not the same. **In Java, you assign variables by value and not by reference.** So, if you modify `first` after assigning it to `node`, it doesn't modify the value of `node`.

It's like,

```
a = 5;
b = a;
a = 4;
```

Here, value of `b` will be `5`. It doesn't get changed to `4`.
Compiler executes each statement sequentially. So it will not know that the value of `a` will be modified in the future or not.

Comment: Yes, that is the case with primitives. Though (and correct me if I'm wrong, I am after all new to programming) objects behave a little differently.  
`Something t1 = new Something(1);`  
`Something t2 = t1;`  
`//t1 and t2 both reference the same Something-instance`  

`t1.someValue=400;`  
`//This will not only change someValue for t1 but also for t2 as they`  
`// reference the same object`  

Because the above `first` and `prev`are both Node objects shouldn't similar logic apply to them?

Comment: I think I figured it out. In my code I am not changing the actual object, I am just changing what objects are being referenced. In plain english my code in the else-block can be read as:  
1. Set `node.next` to reference the object that `first` is referencing.  
2. Set `first.prev` to reference the object that `node` is referencing.  
3. Lastly, reassign `first` to reference the object that `node` is referencing.